# Why I can't get session in login page when session not destroyed in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I have set session after Login successful( Login Link : http://www.example.com/login ). Now I am in profile page. -> http://www.example.com/customer/account/profile.
When I print session in profile page, I get my session value for user(customer). But when I directly change url to login page (http://www.example.com/login) without session destroy and print session value in login page then it shows empty array on login page.

In routes/web.php file :

```
Route::get('/login','LoginController@index');
Route::post('/login/chklogin','LoginController@chkLogin');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer', 'middleware' => 'customer' ], function()
 {
    Route::get('customer/dashboard','customer\DashboardController@index');
    Route::get('customer/account/profile','customer\account\ProfileController@index');
    Route::post('/account/profile/update','customer\account\ProfileController@update');

 });
```

In Customer middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!session()->get('customerLoggedIn')) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    else
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

I want to put get something like this in middleware or in any controller's constructor.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // if session not set for customer then redirect to login page

    // if session set for customer then redirect to profile page
}
```

I wnat to set functionality that, though I change url to login page (http://www.example.com/login), but if my session is not destroyed then it should redirect to profile page (http://www.example.com/customer/account/profile). but it is not working. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of laravel?
Are the routes wrapped in a group in the routes file?

Comment: @JuanCortés : version is: 5.3.31. and yes, routes are wrapped in groups as mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

Probably that `LoginController`'s `index` method is destroying the session. It makes sense to prevent corrupted data for me.

Anyway, you don't need that kind of middleware, that is all handled by `auth` middleware

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'customer', 'middleware' => 'auth' ], function() {

    // protected routes here

 });
```